# Could not cast value of type XX to XX in swift 3

Tags: mapkit, swift3

In **Swift 3 contains method** is always giving error. In the below code `if annotation is MKAnnotation` is passed and goest to next line. Then it gives error. I have searched a lot but not able to find the problem. Any solution for this issue?

**Class declaration:**

```
open class FBAnnotation : NSObject {
  open var coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.0936440, longitude: 4.3592340)
  open var title: String? = ""
  open var annotationIndex: Int?
}

extension FBAnnotation : MKAnnotation {
}
```

**Usage:**

```
do {
   if annotation is MKAnnotation {
      if try node.annotations.contains(where: annotation as! (MKAnnotation) throws -> Bool) {
          try node.annotations.remove(at: node.annotations.index(where: annotation as! (MKAnnotation) throws -> Bool)!)
          node.count -= 1
          return true
      }
   }
} catch {
    return false
}
```

Comment: what type is node?  Also instead of the **is** you can use **if let** to unwrap annotation: **if let annotation = annotation as? MKAnnotation {**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in a playground, no casting required.  You cannot pass an annotation as the where parameter.  You must pass in a function that declares whether or not the annotation is the one you are looking for.  Here I consider them a match if they have the same coordinates, although your match criteria may be different.

```
    var annotations = [MKAnnotation]()
    var annotation: Any? = nil
    if let annotation = annotation as? MKAnnotation {
        if let index = annotations.index(where: {
            $0.coordinate.latitude == annotation.coordinate.latitude  &&
            $0.coordinate.longitude == annotation.coordinate.longitude
        }) {
            annotations.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
```

Comment: where condition closure never returns true in this case

Comment: I have updated my question to show the node type. Here node is FBAnnotation this is a type of MKAnnotation

Comment: Actually the closure inside where is never executed. I think that is the problem.